# Wrong projection for vector layer with http protocol

Tags: openlayers, geoserver

I'm using openlayer with geoserver.

I want to create vector layer that sends viewparams to geoserver layer, 
This is easily done with WMS .

however i do that as :

```
           var newLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('layer', 
               {
               strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed({preload: true})]
               , projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
                ,protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
               url:"/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&version=2.4.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=WG:layer&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=json&viewparams=UID:"+id,
    format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
  }),
               styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
                    'default': new OpenLayers.Style(null, {
                        rules: [
                            new OpenLayers.Rule({
                                symbolizer: {
                                    graphic: false,
                                    label: "name",
                                    labelSelect: true,
                                    fontStyle: 'italic'
                                }
                            })
                        ]
                    })
                })});
```

This is work but the problem is the feature projection is wrong .!

while i use the same projection on other wms layers. 
Is the problem with :

1- `OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP`

or

2-`OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")`

and is there another way to send param without using HTTP protcol ?